# cannot import ERC1155Burnable from openzeppelin library

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol";
import "./AdminContract.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
import "@openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Holder.sol";

/**
- Contract uses a single URI which is the monion IPFS URI for hosting metadata
- Contract relies on the metadata to store relevant info about the token such as name, description etc.
- Contract issues tokenId to each token minted
- Contract use is cheaper than if the user deployed a fresh instance of the ERC1155
*/


contract Monion1155 is ERC1155, Ownable, Pausable, ERC2981, ERC1155Supply, ERC1155Holder, ERC1155MintBurn, ERC1155Metadata {

    
    event Minted (uint indexed tokenId,address indexed owner, uint quantity);

    address operator;
    AdminConsole admin;
```

while trying to import  ERC1155
from openzeppelin library giving me the following error :

```
Error: not found @openzeppelin-contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Burnable.sol
```

also someone suggested me to use ERC1155MintBurn but I dont think that library exist on openzep

```
ERC1155MintBurn
```

```
ERC1155MintBurn
```

```
ERC1155MintBurn
```

```
ERC1155MintBurn
```

```
ERC1155MintBurn
```

```
ERC1155MintBurn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Burnable.sol";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).